# Removing unwanted html from an href tag in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, filtering

I want to be able to scrape out a list of links. I cannot due this directly with BeautifulSoup because of the way the html is structured.

```
start_list = soup.find_all(href=re.compile('id='))

print(start_list)

[<a href="/movies/?id=actofvalor.htm"><b>Act of Valor</b></a>,
 <a href="/movies/?id=actionjackson.htm"><b>Action Jackson</b></a>]
```

I am looking to pull just the href information. I am thinking some sort of filter where I can put all of the bold  tags into a list then filter them out of another list which contains the information above.

```
start_list = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('id='))

start_list_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(start_list), 'html.parser')

things_to_remove = start_list_soup.find_all('b')
```

The idea is to be able to loop through things_to_remove and remove all occurrences of its contents from start_list

Comment: post the output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start_list = soup.find_all(href=re.compile('id='))

href_list = [i['href'] for i in start_list]
```

`href` is the attrbute of tag, if you use `find_all` get bunch of tags, just iterate over it and use `tag['href']` to access the attribute.

To understand why use `[]`, you should know that tag's attribute are store in the dictionary.
[Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

> A tag may have any number of attributes. The tag `<b class="boldest">`
>   has an attribute “class” whose value is “boldest”. You can access a
>   tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary:
>
> ```
> tag['class']
> # u'boldest'
> ```
>
> You can access that dictionary directly as .attrs:
>
> ```
> tag.attrs
> # {u'class': u'boldest'}
> ```

list comprehension is simple, you can reference this [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), in this case, it can be done in the for loop:

```
href_list = []
for i in start_list:
    href_list.append(i['href'])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed can you explain the list comprehension a little more to me?

Comment: specifically: this part i['href'] why is it in brackets?

Comment: @ Chace Mcguyer please accept this answer to close this question.